# Symmetric Numbers

Tags: code-golf, string, math, number, function

write a function to tell if a number is symmetric or not. 
for example:

input:
151
output:
True

input:
142
output:
False

and so on:
1111 True, 
2390 False, 
1226221 True

Comment: My question is not a duplicate, your's involve matrix and mine is different

Comment: Your question is largely the same; the older question asks "is it a palindrome in base X" whereas yours asks "is it a palindrome in base 10", so answers to the duplicate question would automatically be competitive here, with very little modification.

Comment: The challenge this was marked as a duplicate of only requires to convert the input to another base. This is just a special case with base \$10\$. By convention, when trivial modifications can be made to port the majority of answers from one challenge to the other while they are still competitive, marking one challenge as a duplicate of the other is recommended.

Comment: Either way, welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Don't let the fact that your first challenge was marked as a dupe discourage you from posting in the future! In fact, to avoid such situations we have a [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges), where you can show your challenge to others prior to posting on the main site to receive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 23 bytes

```python
lambda n:`n`==`n`[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKiEvwdYWSERbWekaxv4vKMrMK1FI0zA0NdRUVsgvLSkoLbFSCCkqTeXigsuZGCHJuSXmFCNLAgFQFqRDRwEuamRsaQAUBatFEjY0MjIzMoKp/w8A)